# iOS ADAL Authentication Flow

Tags: ios, authentication, azure, office365, adal

I have a feeling I'm missing something extremely obvious...

I'm using ADAL with native iOS application. Connecting to Azure, etc, etc.

Up until recently, this flow was working for me. As of today, it has appeared to be broken.

I have a LogInController that I got from the office365 sdk for iOS. The following method:

```
-(void) getTokenWith :(NSString *)resourceId : (BOOL) clearCache completionHandler:(void (^) (NSString *))completionBlock; {
if([self getCacheToken : resourceId completionHandler:completionBlock]) return;

ADAuthenticationError *error;
authContext = [ADAuthenticationContext authenticationContextWithAuthority:authority error:&error];

NSURL *redirectUri = [NSURL URLWithString:redirectUriString];

[authContext acquireTokenWithResource:resourceId
                             clientId:clientId
                          redirectUri:redirectUri
                      completionBlock:^(ADAuthenticationResult  *result) {

                          if (AD_SUCCEEDED != result.status){
                              [self showError:result.error.errorDetails];
                          }
                          else{
                              NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                              [userDefaults setObject:result.tokenCacheStoreItem.userInformation.userId forKey:@"LogInUser"];
                              [userDefaults synchronize];

                              completionBlock(result.accessToken);
                          }
                      }];}
```

That I call in this method that gets called on in the viewDidLoad() on my rootViewController.

```
- (void)logIn {
_resourceId = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"SharePointResourceId"];
_userURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", _resourceId, SharePointResourceUserEndPoint];

LogInController *logInController = [[LogInController alloc] init];

[logInController getTokenWith:_resourceId :false completionHandler:^(NSString *token) {

    if (token == nil) {

        NSLog(@"newADALLogIn: No user access token exists");

    } else {
        //User is authenicated, Go get the Current user data object
        NSString *userToken = token;
        NSString *userId = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"LogInUser"];
        [userId stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSString *completeUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", _userURL, userId, UserSelectProperties];
        NSString *authTokenBearer = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@", userToken];

        NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:completeUrl];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
        [request setValue:authTokenBearer forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"accept"];

        @try {
            AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
            operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

            [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

                //Doing UI stuff

            } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
            }];

            [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperation:operation];
        }
        @catch (NSException *exception) {
            NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", exception);
        }
    }
}];}
```

The issue that I'm having now is the first time the user logs in. It properly redirects to the o365 web auth view. User is able to auth fine, then the home view controller displays. However, the code:

```
//User is authenicated, Go get the Current user data object
        NSString *userToken = token;
        NSString *userId = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"LogInUser"];
        [userId stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSString *completeUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", _userURL, userId, UserSelectProperties];
        NSString *authTokenBearer = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@", userToken];

        NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:completeUrl];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
        [request setValue:authTokenBearer forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"accept"];

        @try {
            AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
            operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

            [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

                //Doing UI stuff

            } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
            }];

            [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperation:operation];
        }
        @catch (NSException *exception) {
            NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", exception);
        }
```

Never gets called. In the past, after auth, that code would execute. Any suggestions are appreciative.

Comment: Whats your current ADAL version? Did you update your version recently?

Comment: In my pod file:       pod 'ADALiOS', '~> 1.0.2'

Comment: Had another set of eyes look at my code and figured the issue was something else I had going on. So, this is a non-issue. Thanks Kanishk for responding.